# Output counts grouped by field values by for date in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a Splunk index named `http_logs` with the following fields:

- _time
- status_code
- status_text
- requester

I'm trying to use this data to create a table that looks like this:

| Requester | Today | Yesterday | Last Seven Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Service 1 | 100 (2) | 300 (4) | 2000 (7) |
| Service 2 | 120 (3) | 275 (3) | 2400 (9) |

...

As the table above shows, each column has two values:

1. The number of `http_logs` with a `status_code` in the range of 200-299 for the time range (ie. today, yesterday, last seven days)
2. The number of `http_logs` with a `status_code` outside of 200-299 for the time range (ie. today, yesterday, last seven days)

Currently, I have the following Splunk query:

```
index="http_logs"
earliest=-6d@d
latest=now
| fields requester status_code _time
| table requester
```

I don't know how to format a table while grouping fields with specific values though. Is this even possible with a Splunk query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splunk tables usually have one value in each cell.  To put multiple values in a cell we usually concatenate the values into a single value.

To get counts for different time periods, we usually run separate searches and combine the results.

Note the use of `sum` instead of `count` in the `stats` commands.  This is because the `eval` function always returns a value (0 or 1) and counting them would give the total number of results rather than the number of events that match the condition.

````
```Get today's events```
index=http_logs earliest=@d
| eval success=if(status_code>=200 status_code<=299, 1, 0)
```Count successes and failures```
| stats sum(eval(success=1)) as today_success, sum(eval(success=0)) as today_fail by requester
```Repeat for yesterday's events```
| append [ search index=http_logs earliest=-1d@d latest=@d
  | eval success=if(status_code>=200 status_code<=299, 1, 0)
  | stats sum(eval(success=1)) as yesterday_success, sum(eval(success=0)) as yesterday_fail by requester ]
```Repeat for the last 7 days' events```
| append [ search index=http_logs earliest=-7d@d latest=now
  | eval success=if(status_code>=200 status_code<=299, 1, 0)
  | stats sum(eval(success=1)) as sevenday_success, sum(eval(success=0)) as sevenday_fail by requester ]
```Put the results together```
| stats values(*) as * by requester
```Build the display values```
| eval Today = today_success . " (" . today_fail . ")"
| eval Yesterday = yesterday_success . " (" . yesterday_fail . ")"
| eval "Last Seven Days" = sevenday_success . " (" . sevenday_fail . ")"
| rename requester as Requester
```Display the results```
| table Requester Today Yesterday "Last Seven Days"
````